# Am I doing these if statements correctly?

Tags: linux, bash

Below is a section of my script where I'm not sure if I did the if statements correctly. Especially the if after the elfif - can I do that?

```
read -p 'Enter username: ' user 
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "You must supply a user name argument"
    exit 1
elif grep "${user}" /etc/passwd >/dev/null 2>&1 then 
    read -p 'Are you sure you want to delete user orange? [y/n] ' response
if [[ ! $response =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]] then
    del-user
else
    echo "User orange has not been deleted."
fi
else
    add-user
fi
```

Edit: I'm trying to figure out if my syntax is correct.

Comment: At first glance, this seems like valid syntax, although badly indented. You should mention what result you're trying to achieve. Unless you only want advice with syntax? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @mesr Can you tell me how the indentation is bad? I thought it was fine lol. Sorry for not being clear, but yes I wanted to make sure my syntax was correct. I wasn't sure if I was using the if/elif/else's correctly

Comment: There should be semicolon in front of every `then` (or put it on the next line). The 'inner if-else-fi statement' should be indented relative to the 'outer if-elif-else-fi statement', otherwise it is easy to get confused.

Comment: @sudodus I don't know why I can't upvote comments but thank you

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help you :-)

Comment: First `if` should be `if [ -z "$user" ]; then`

Comment: @RomeoNinov oops, thanks

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ is really good at catching small errors.